# C++: Is this a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I create std::vector of MyClass1. I don't use any pointers to that class so I wanna know: is my way of using std::vector safety or have I a problem with the memory leaks here?

Why am I asking it? I've added constuctor and destructor to MyClass1 and there are never call. That's my code:

```
class MyClass1 {
public:
    MyClass1() {
        printf( "constructor\n" );
    }
    ~MyClass1() {
        printf( "destructor\n" );
    }
    int var1;
    std::string str;
};

std::vector< MyClass1 > testArr;

MyClass1 gr1;

gr1.var1 = 111;
testArr.push_back( gr1 );

gr1.var1 = 122;
testArr.push_back( gr1 );

printf( "testArr.at( 1 ).var1 = %i\n", testArr.at( 1 ).var1 );
```

It calls the constructor but it never calls the destructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is leak free.

vector manages its own memory, so won't leak by itself. And you're using local instances of MyClass and copying them, which won't leak either. Finally, the string member of MyClass manages its memory in the same way as vector, so no leaks there.

When worrying about leaks, just avoid using raw new/delete and use smart pointers instead, use standard containers like you are here, and don't allocate memory unless you really have to.

To address your lack of constructor/destructor calls... what you are probably seeing is the effect of compiler optimisations. Try running again with optimisation fully off, and see what gets called.

Edit:

I just ran this code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class MyClass1 {
public:
    MyClass1() {
        printf( "constructor\n" );
    }
    ~MyClass1() {
        printf( "destructor\n" );
    }
    int var1;
    string str;
};

int main()
{
    vector< MyClass1 > testArr;

    MyClass1 gr1;

    gr1.var1 = 111;
    testArr.push_back( gr1 );

    gr1.var1 = 122;
    testArr.push_back( gr1 );

    printf( "testArr.at( 1 ).var1 = %i\n", testArr.at( 1 ).var1 );

   return 0;
}
```

... with GCC 4.7.2, optimisations OFF and got this output:

```
constructor
destructor
testArr.at( 1 ).var1 = 122
destructor
destructor
destructor
```

Comment: But why it doesn't call the destructor of every added element to the std::vector?

Comment: @JavaRunner Edited to suggest why

Comment: How can you turn off optimisations on GCC? :) I also use GCC.

Comment: Where you might see -O2 or -Os, swap it for -O0

Answer (score 1):

The code you've shown is leak free.  The destructor will only be called when the destructor of `testArr` is called or if you call `testArr.clear()`.

In the example, `gr1` is copied or moved (if possible) into the vector.  The destructor will be called when `gr1` goes out of scope, or the elements in the vector are removed.  None of which happen in the example code which means that the destructor will not be called.

Once the method exits (not shown in your code) you should see the destructor being called three times.  Twice for the elements in the `vector` and once for `gr1`.

Comment: I thought it should call the destructor for every added element to the std::vector. Why that doesn't work like this?

Comment: @JavaRunner Did you try flushing the output stream? Could be something like that. It really should work as you expect.